# How to center two text views inside a Constraint Layout constantly spaced?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I've this layout for a RecyclerView(standard stuff omitted):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_tv_movie_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/id_tv_movie_release_year"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_tv_movie_release_year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/id_tv_movie_name" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when I add really long and really short titles I get this:

[image]

Colored lines show every row has the exact distance between 
`startOfParent-startOf1-endOf1-startOf2-endOf2-endOfParent`.

How can I separate this textViews into 2 constant width columns and when title is bigger, break it into more lines?

Something like

```
  The Lord of The Rings:                        2001
The FellowShip of the Ring
           MIB                                  1997
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid might be useful (`TableLayout`)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title asdf asdf asdg asgasdg asdfg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="66dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2015"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to split the item so that each `TextView` consumes a constant width is to specify `layout_constraintWidth_percent` like this for 50% of the width:

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
```

To allocate 70% of the width to the title (centered) and 30% to the year (right-justified), do the following:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_tv_movie_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very Long Movie Title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/id_tv_movie_release_year"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_tv_movie_release_year"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="2002"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which will display the following:

[image]

The same layout can be made with a horizontal chain and layout weights if other than a 50/50 split is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy option that you can use is [chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html):

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```